# GDAL framework does not exist after KyngChaos installation of QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, mac, anaconda

I'm on a Macbook running Sierra 10.12, so I used the KyngChaos [installation](https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/) of QGIS 3.8. I followed the instructions in the ReadMe, and installed python (though I already had it on my machine), GDAL and then QGIS. I took notice of the 'known issue' as well and created a prepend PATH variable so QGIS could load the GDAL framework, but it did not work. After searching the app's package contents, I realized that there is no "GDAL.framework" folder on my machine even though I downloaded it from the instructions.

I used EasyFind and noticed that I have gdal installed in anaconda, can I use this path for QGIS to be able to load the module? If not, how can I download GDAL so that QGIS can recognize it and it shows up on my machine? I'm not sure why the KyngChaos installation is broken (it's worth noting that the path in the ReadMe file is incorrect as well).

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot of the frameworks folder within the app's package contents, alphabetically sorted. As you can see, there is no GDAL.framework.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is already resolved but while installing QGIS 3.4 of the KyangChaos website I also got stuck on the "known issue" part.
On the website it states you have to prepend variable PATH with value:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Programs:

The above doesn't refer to the Frameworks of the QGIS app however. The only thing is that you should check which GDAL.framework/Versions/ exists on your computer. In my case I had to change 2.2 to 2.4 to make it work. So the above value in my case becomes:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs:

Hope this helps. Good luck!